# SQL Server Normalisation/Best Practices: Single Data Table

Tags: sql-server, types, normalization

I have inherited the maintenance of a database from a former employee in another department and I believe their database development skills are not really up to snuff.

I have been asked to support or redevelop it.

It appears the database of the data for each record is in one single table, Yes I know and has hundreds of thousands of rows with empty fields.

```
TableData:
> RowID
> FieldID
> DateData
> NumberData
> TextData
> YesNoData
```

Only one field (dependent on the datatype required) appears to be populated in this instance for each row - the rest are empty.

There are two other tables which identify details of the Record (Created by etc) and the Field (Updated On, Field datatype)

Looking through the Access front-end code it appears that data for each field and record and field is stored by searching on record and field and then returning the appropriate field with the data.

My question: For what purpose does this achieve, or is this type of development considered the work of an inexperienced database developer?

Comment: It's basically very hard to answer. Without seeing the application requirement, structure, and details, no one can truly tell why this database designing was opted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that a table like this is used to store arbitrary data (inferred from the other supporting tables) that won't require schema changes to store information that is "unplanned" or not yet implemented in the business logic of the application.

The questions I would start asking (yourself, any programmers, DBA's, project managers, etc.):

- Were the requirements so abstract at the time that it was impossible to create a formal schema with data relationships? (Bad, bad, BAD)
- Was the database designer lazy or inexperienced?
- Was the programmer lazy or inexperienced? (Better yet, was the programmer the DBA?)
- Is the reliability/availability of the data so sensitive that making formal schema changes is hard to do on a regular basis?
- Has the project gone through plenty of people before you that simply inherited the problems, and this is a hack solution? (While maybe the original programmer knew where it was intended to go eventually...)

I think what you're really trying to get at here is "does this work, or should I change it?".  I'd be shocked if the any read/search queries are optimized at all, as there couldn't be any indexes for such arbitrary data storage.  If the application is simply logging information, it probably isn't as big of a deal, as the originator probably just didn't know yet how the data would be used later on, and writing a one-time applet to loop through and create formal objects out of the data would be better than trying to assume everything at the beginning.

Getting a little more targeted, are you running into any bottlenecks in your process because of this particular table, or are you concerned just out of surprise? If the former, I'd figure out how to change it right away.  If the latter, I'd take my time figuring out the long-term requirements of the application first.

Comment: The database was developed without any knowledge of our IT department, and hence why I am now inheriting the application. Delving into the logic of the database, it appears several Access forms with different sets of fields are hooking into this one table.

Comment: The DB was designed without any IT knowledge, which is required here. I assume the guy went on an short Access/VBA course and considered himself "an expert".  Basically, it is a data-entry logging application recording different types of data for the finance dept.

Comment: Each form a dfferent set of unbound up to 100 control fields and one "maintenance" screen to link these controls to the record and field back to the database. My concern is the long term viability and performance with 893,135 records to be precise. I have to now support it, and the question was asked if redevelopment was an option. My question is: Is this single 'compact' structure good for data entry/retrieval and what purpose does it achieve? Each record would need to return 100+ records instead of 1 record from a strucured table. However, will one long 100+ have performance issues?

Comment: Undoubtedly yes.  Try running "EXPLAIN EXTENDED" (just put those two words right before "SELECT") with one of the read queries and my guess is you'll see a long list of temporary tables and/or file sorts.  Do you have an example sql query you can show here?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot part 1 of your question.  No, it's not good for anything but abstracting the logic on the application side so you don't have to create a new table and write new queries every time the accounting department asks "hey, can I run a report on...?"

Comment: But ironically, I'm about to do the exact same thing with a Forms plugin for my CMS.  The problem is abstraction.  I want to report on schema-less data, but each form will have different data.  It's more of a document-oriented data design, rather than relational.  There is a place for it, but rarely in an RDBMS...